Msteams bot /invoke api failing with 502 error and bot sending multiple requests to hooks endpoint
We are using msteams bot using botframework-connector and botbuilder, both or v4.20.1
Whenever a user clicks on some buttons on adaptive cards, they are getting following message below the card, though bot responds just fine: Error screenshot
Again, they are seeing the error in red box, but bot responds back accordingly.
Upon checking the network tab, one /invoke api gets called and fails with 502 bad gateway.
endpoint: https://teams.microsoft.com/api/chatsvc/in/v1/agents/28:<ourAppId>/invoke
payload: (I have redacted sensitive ids and details from the payload)
{
  "name": "messageback",
  "text": "Go to 7th module",
  "messageType": "RichText/Media_Card",
  "value": {
    "id": "66ea60cab0xxxxx",
    "title": "Go to 7th module",
    "type": "quickReply"
  },
  "imdisplayname": "Saurabh Jagtap",
  "userAadToken": "eyJ0eXAREDACTED",
  "serverMessageId": "17266xxxxxx",
  "clientMessageId": "4774xxxx",
  "conversation": {
    "id": "19:871c85b1xxxxxx@unq.gbl.spaces"
  }
}

response:
{
    "errorCode": 1008,
    "message": "<BotError>Error when sending request to bot",
    "standardizedError": {
        "errorCode": 1008,
        "errorSubCode": 1,
        "errorDescription": "<BotError>Error when sending request to bot"
    }
}

There has been no change recently from our end. It started coming up out of nowhere suddenly.
I have tried reinstalling the app, make sure the hooks endpoint is giving back 200 ok response. Also made sure that its not timing out.
EDIT:
Seems like another issue started coming up where hooks endpoint is getting multiple requests 4 times, as if microsoft is retrying the request.
Same /invoke api was failing. But it was calling itself for the 4 times, giving back the same 502 error, and now we were getting the error in red box after the 4th failed /invoke api call. Its like msteams is sending the 4 copies of user responses to the hooks endpoint attached with the bot. This has started by itself recently.
screenshot.

If the bot doesn't complete the operation within 10 to 15 seconds, depending on the channel, the Azure Bot Service will time out and report back to the client a 504:GatewayTimeout, as described in How bots work.
For proper handling of managing long running operation please refer below doc.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-long-operations-guidance?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

Its giving 502 to me and bot is responding back in couple of seconds. @Sayali-MSFT

also added new issue that started coming up again @Sayali-MSFT

can you please check here once? this is hampering on our production env and needs to be addressed asap.

If you have any business-critical issue which need immediate attention, please raise a support request here:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/get-help-support?view=o365-worldwide&tabs=online
